# how to solve NotOfficeXmlFileException

Tags: java, excel, unit-testing, junit, apache-poi

I have an API for uploading excel file to a server and read it, so my code below

```
public ReturnSTH funcExample(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    Sheet sheet = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something
    }
```

then I have to test the API using JUnit as below

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MockMultipartFile fakeFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "bank.xlsx", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "file data".getBytes());
    ReturnSTH response = funcExample(fakeFile);
}
```

I got the error like below

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
```

on the line **Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);**

I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like your file isn't actually a XLSX file... If you open it up in Excel and do a Save-As, what format type does Excel think it is?

Comment: @Gagravarr actually, it's working fine on the func but it failed on the test. i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for test:

```
String originalName = "src/main/resources/test.xlsx";
    File testFile = new File(originalName);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(testFile);
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", testFile.getName(), MediaType.ALL_VALUE, stream);
```

Just use **FileInputStream** and use .xlsx format